# Get indices of the first element in a python list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this one:

[[21], [22, 1], [23, 2], [24, 1, 0, 4], [25, 2, 3]]

and I want to append to a new list the indices of the first item of each sublist, while counting all elements in all the sublists. Each index of the new list depends on the length of each sublist. The result I am looking for is this one:

[0, 1, 3, 5, 9].

I don't want to use numpy or any other library.
Thanks!

Comment: you need to make a four loop to go through the main list and another for loop inside it to go through each item

Comment: What about builtin modules like `itertools`? With a current version of Python you could do `list(itertools.accumulate(l, lambda total, x: total + len(x), initial=0))[:-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
l = [[21], [22, 1], [23, 2], [24, 1, 0, 4], [25, 2, 3]]

n = []
p = 0
for s1 in l:
    n.append(p)
    p += len(s1)

print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the lengths starting with zero:

```
L = [[21], [22, 1], [23, 2], [24, 1, 0, 4], [25, 2, 3]]

from itertools import accumulate
idx = [0,*accumulate(map(len,L[:-1]))]

print(idx) # [0, 1, 3, 5, 9]
```